# Getting new token (with refresh_token) in Azure OAuth gives 404 from NodejS, works fine from cURL

Tags: node.js, azure, https, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get a new token from Azure but am getting 404 errors. When I dump the request body & parameters, and then convert it to a cURL request, everything works perfectly though. Any ideas what it could be?

```
{ host: 'login.microsoftonline.com',
  method: 'POST',
  port: 443,
  path: '/common/oauth2/token',
  headers:
   { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   }  
}
```

And the request body:

```
refresh_token=SNIP&client_id=SNIP&client_secret=SNIP&grant_type=refresh_token
```

I know the tokens & client info are right because it works in curl..

I'm using Node's `https.request` library to make the call. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Ted, any updates yet?

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT yes, and thank you so much for the help! My problem was trying to use the general path rather than the tenant-specific one. I just marked it as correct and upvoted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the completed sample about getting access token by refresh token via `https.request`:

```
var https = require('https');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var postData = querystring.stringify({
  refresh_token: "<refresh_token>",
  client_id: "<client_id>",
  client_secret:"<client_secret>",
  grant_type:"refresh_token"
});
var options = {
  hostname: 'login.microsoftonline.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers:
   { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': postData.length
   } 
};



var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
  var result = '';
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    result += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function () {
    console.log(result);
  });
  res.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
});

// req error
req.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});

//send request witht the postData form
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.